# Failed to load resource in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, glyphicons

I'm using **Bootstrap-sass (3.3.5, 3.3.1.0, 3.2.0.2)**

My font files are saved on the following path:

> app/assets/fonts/bootstrap

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

And when I render a page, I get this error:

```
Started GET "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-09 14:50:55 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"):
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (22.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (146.0ms)
```

I have also tried moving them to:

> app/assets/fonts

But still fails.

Comment: try to assist them with this syntax => "assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a fonts folder to the public directory:

```
public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your assets paths in `config/application.rb` to load the `app/assets/fonts` directory ?

if not, you can add something like this to it:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Once you've done that you should also load your fonts in your sass/less/css/whatever files from the public compiled assets directory. For exemple in sass, you can do it this way with the helper `asset-url`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: asset-url('myfont.eot');
  src: asset-url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset-url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
  // etc ...
}
```

You can read more about how assets works here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Hi Na0na0, I tried what you suggested and did not work. I just read from your link reference that: The asset pipeline is technically no longer a core feature of Rails 4, it has been extracted out of the framework into the sprockets-rails gem.

Comment: It also say that it is enabled by default, and since you are using bootstrap-sass, I don't how you would not be using it since it is a dependance of the bootstrap-sass gem: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/bootstrap-sass.gemspec
Unless you are using gulp/bower/npm/... and used `--skip-sprockets` when you created your app ? Please tag your question properly if so, so people with the right knowledge can help you.